# Dropdown List in Catalyst

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

I am trying to add a dropdown list in my SwiftUI catalyst app.  from what I read you have to use the picker, but it does not let you use the popupbuttonpicker style on iOS. so how can I achieve a Mac style dropdown list in catalyst? I assume I have to basically roll my own out using views and popups?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your app setting to "Optimize interface for Mac"

[image: Setting on Xcode]